# Add boundaries to a UIPangesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UILabel` in a `subview` and I have a `panGesture` and `pinchGesture` on the `UILabel`. As of right now I can move the `UILabel` crossed all views. I want this `UILabel` do stay within the area of the `subView`. How would I accomplish this?

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture {
CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:panGesture.view.superview];

if (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == panGesture.state ||UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged == panGesture.state) {
    panGesture.view.center = CGPointMake(panGesture.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         panGesture.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
 }
}
```

In this line,

```
CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:panGesture.view.superview];
```

It is setting it to the superView and I am trying to set it to my subView but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code to handle draggable button and restrict it to the main view boundary
I hope this code will help you

```
 CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    CGRect recognizerFrame = recognizer.view.frame;
    recognizerFrame.origin.x += translation.x;
    recognizerFrame.origin.y += translation.y;

    // Check if UIImageView is completely inside its superView
    if (CGRectContainsRect(self.view.bounds, recognizerFrame)) {
        recognizer.view.frame = recognizerFrame;
    }
    // Else check if UIImageView is vertically and/or horizontally outside of its
    // superView. If yes, then set UImageView's frame accordingly.
    // This is required so that when user pans rapidly then it provides smooth translation.
    else {
        // Check vertically
        if (recognizerFrame.origin.y < self.view.bounds.origin.y) {
            recognizerFrame.origin.y = 0;
        }
        else if (recognizerFrame.origin.y + recognizerFrame.size.height > self.view.bounds.size.height) {
            recognizerFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - recognizerFrame.size.height;
        }

        // Check horizantally
        if (recognizerFrame.origin.x < self.view.bounds.origin.x) {
            recognizerFrame.origin.x = 0;
        }
        else if (recognizerFrame.origin.x + recognizerFrame.size.width > self.view.bounds.size.width) {
            recognizerFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.size.width - recognizerFrame.size.width;
        }
    }

    // Reset translation so that on next pan recognition
    // we get correct translation value
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
```

Comment: Thanks for the helping. Would you be willing to help me understand how I could implement this into my own code?